# Drawing a specific color in the image editor

Tags: image

I'm trying to do something that seems very elementary but I can't figure it out: I want to make a 8x1 px bitmap and give each pixel a specific value in the Blender image editor. My first problem is that I can't resize the brush ('Draw' tool) small enough; it's always bigger than 1 pixel so I draw on other pixels. Secondly I can't find a blend mode that will just assign the color that I chose in the Color Picker; it always adjusts the existing color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your falloff should be adjusted. Mine stops after radius 1 (2 is the diameter)
I was able to paint pixels successfully without modifying other pixels. Let me know if you need the blend file.
Cheers!
[image: view1]

[image: view2]

Comment: Ah I see, yes after some fiddling I now understand how it works. Thanks!

Comment: (for anyone trying after me: it solves both aspects of my question as long as the falloff is steep enough; I put mine at a full drop about midway, that makes most sense to me conceptually)